# When creating a AzureFile persistent volume via a dynamic persistent volume claim the AzureFile created has no metadata

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-files

I'm successfully creating persistent volumes dynamically on Azure using the `kubernetes.io/azure-file` provider. I can configure it to use the storage account I want and I'm generally happy *except* the resultant objects in Azure (as viewed through the Azure portal or using az cli) have no metadata associated with them.

I'd like to contrast this with the setup I have on AWS using the `kubernetes.io/aws-ebs` where the EBS volumes get tagged with tags like `KubernetesCluster`, `Name`, `kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name` and `kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/name`.

This info was invaluable when we lost our cluster and had to write a script to re-attach these existing volumes by creating PVs. It's also useful for a host of other reasons.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour with the `kubernetes.io/azure-file` ?

Comment: Where do you want to get this information? inside the Kubernetes or in the Azure resource?

Comment: @CharlesXu I would like this information on the Azure resources and viewable through the Azure portal. This is the way our current AWS set up works (obviously the AWS console, under EC2 -> block storage). I find this information useful when there is an issue with the cluster etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way to meet your requirement is the metadata of the file share. But you need to add the info you want to the metadata yourself.

> Metadata for a share or file resource is stored as name-value pairs
>   associated with the resource. Metadata names must adhere to the naming
>   rules for C# identifiers.

[image]

For more details, see [Metadata names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-shares--directories--files--and-metadata#metadata-names).

Comment: I thought this might be the case. That's a shame. I'd submit a feature request but I'm not quite sure where...

Comment: @tam203 OK, now you know where is it. Glad it's the thing you want.

Comment: I've raised a feature request for the behaviour I want - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/82881